# Labelling ArrayPlot Charts

Tags: plotting, visualization

I have been using `ArrayPlot` to show off some information. Currently, my datasets are like so:

```
data1={2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5, 13, 11, 33, 21, 29, 21, 42, 29, 36};
data2={0, 1, 9, 1, 3, 0, 5, 3, 20, 16, 4, 13, 7, 10, 7};
data3={10, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 14, 2, 1, 12, 6, 0, 10};
data4={0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 1, 3, 2};
data5={0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 14, 4, 2, 4};
```

etc.

The plot command

```
ArrayPlot[{globeCHR, starCHR, telegramCHR, gazetteCHR, citizenCHR}, 
 FrameTicks -> All]
```

reveals the following:

[image]

So far so good - it vividly shows what I am trying to visualize.

The problem comes with the following. I would like to give my datasets along the y axis names: i.e. instead of "1" it might say "Cats" and instead of "2" it might say "Dogs." Similarly, the bottom axis needs to go from 1997 to 2010 (years).

I have generated a list of the years as such `yearlist = Range[1997, 2011, 1]`, which lines up in length to the datasets. Matched pairs of data created by `Transpose@` the two lists hasn't worked either..

Would there be a way to have the x axis demonstrate the text of the datasets, and the y axis show the data progressing from the year 1997 to 2010? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `FrameTicks` should be entered in the following format:

```
FrameTicks->{
    {{ytick1, yvalue1}, {ytick2, yvalue2},...}, 
    {{xtick1, xvalue1}, {xtick2, xvalue2},...}
}
```

So here's an example for your case that shows how to label the ticks:

```
xticks = Transpose[{Range@15, Range[1997, 2011]}];
yticks = Transpose[{Range@5, {"Cats", "Dogs", "Sheep", "Frogs", "Mice"}}];
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {5, 15}], FrameTicks -> {yticks, xticks}]
```

[image]

Comment: This fails for me if you are doing a 2x2 array, as in 

`ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {#1, #2}], 
   FrameTicks -> {yticks[[;; #1]], xticks[[;; #2]]}] &[2, 2]`. It works in other cases. As a workaround for the 2x2 case, just add on a junk value for `xticks` or `yticks`, it will just ignore the extra. For example, this works `ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {#1, #2}], 
   FrameTicks -> {yticks, xticks[[;; #2]]}] &[2, 2]`. There is probably a better way of doing in though. (`yticks` and `xticks` are as defined in your answer).