# Is it possible to substitute tick labels with alternative text?

Tags: plotting, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Labelling ArrayPlot Charts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/labelling-arrayplot-charts)

I am making a `MatrixPlot`.  For example, consider the following:

```
list = {{1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}};
MatrixPlot[list]
```

which yields:

[image: MatrixPlot]

But now suppose I want to label the axes with other numbers.  For example, I would like to label the ticks on the horizontal axis as 101, 167, 188, 205 (as they are not now), and the ticks on the vertical axis as 1, 2, 3 (as they already are).  I know this is a strange request, but it is because I would like to label the horizontal axis according to "particle number" (which is an integer in my application).

Or maybe a better way to phrase the question is, is it possible to label axis/frame ticks with *any* arbitrary string (for example, labeling the horizontal axis with `"Alice"`, `"Bob"`, `"Carla"`, and `"David"`)?  One possibility seems like `FrameTicks`, but I can't seem to figure out if it can be used to map strings.

If I use

```
list = {{1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}};
MatrixPlot[list, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{1, 2, 3}, None}, {{101, 167, 188, 205}, None}}]
```

I get:

[image: MatrixPlot]

because, of course, `FrameTicks` thinks I'm referring to which discrete values to label.

Also, if I try:

```
list = {{1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}};
MatrixPlot[list, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{1, 2, 3}, None}, {{"101", "167", "188", "205"}, 
    None}}]
```

I get "Not a valid tick specification."

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I believe this was covered in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-tick-marks-larger.

Comment: This doesn't work because the frame ticks specification needs positions to determine where to place the labels. If you use numbers mma assumes positions == labels, and with the high values you're using they are out of the plot range. In the case of the strings as labels there is no position information at all.

Comment: This question is about something qualitatively different than the above-referenced question. FDSg's answer below is correct, and this should not be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @StevenBedrick  Can we change it from not duplicate to duplicate?  This question was directly useful to me where as the other answer was not.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try this

```
 MatrixPlot[list,  
 FrameTicks -> {
 {{1, 2, 3}, None}, {{{1, 101}, {2, 167}, {3, 188}, {4, 205}}, {{1, "Alice"}, {2,"Bob"}}}
 }]
```

[image]