# ListDensity plot does not plot the actual data set

Tags: plotting, matrix

I have a dataset here [here](http://pastebin.com/1eMDPXHB). It consists of three columns. It x values or the column 1  is not the same for all the data sets for corresponding z values (or in other words, **x values are not equally spaced**). But I would like to make a 2D color plot. It turns out that when I use the following

```
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

will give a very wierd value.

[image]

If you look at the data set one can easily understand that it only has a three data sets combined. In principle the image must have three strips along the horizontal axis, instead, it has many strips.

Clearly, ListDesnity plot is not doing a good job here.How do I fix this?

**EDIT**

The point is that it has 3 x 651 (Y x X) data points. Clearly, from the plot, it is very clear that it has not been plotting that many data points when the Interpolation is zero. That is pretty weird by the way.

I need the actual data points without any sort of additional filtering like smoothing or anything.

Instead, of plotting {x,y,z} values directly in ListDensityPlot, I had used Matrix method something like the following, first make the partition the z value as 31x3 Matrix, then plot in list density plot. But this clearly does not work here since x values for three different sets (y) are not uniform. Or in other words for example. I have a data something like this

```
set1 = {{x,1,z11},{{x,2,z12},{x,3,z13}};
set2 = {{x2,1.1,z21},{{x2,2.5,z22},{x2,2.7,z23}}
set3={{x3,1.1,z31},{{x3,2.2,z32},{x3,3.5,z33}}
mydata=Join[set1,set2,set].
```

what I do not have is something like this.

```
set1 = {{x,1,z11},{{x,2,z12},{x,3,z13}};
set2 = {{x2,1,z21},{{x2,2,z22},{x2,3,z23}}
set3={{x3,1,z21},{{x3,2,z22},{x3,3,z23}}
Notmydata=Join[set1,set2,set].
```

Comment: I do not fully understand your question, but I can see that the plot looks weird. To get rid of the white rectangles, use `PlotRange -> All`.  These have values that are clipped otherwise.  I do not understand what you mean by `x` not being equally spaced.  The `x` values are the same for `y=200`, `300` and `400`. Also, I do see three strips along the horizontal axis, so I do not understand this comment.  Use `Mesh -> All` to see them better.  However, the middle strip is made of many more parts than the top and bottom.This is weird and looks incorrect. The middle is wider, but that's fixable.

Comment: Is you data structured as `{{x, y, z}, ...}` or `{{x, ...}, {y, ...}, {z, ...}}`? To me, it looks like your data is in the latter form, not the former.

Comment: why are you using `InterpolationOrder->0`?

Comment: @ Szabolcs, I am sorry that the x values are different for y= 200, 300 and 400 but in the same range

Comment: @rcollyer Our data is in the second form

Comment: @ george2079, otherwise I get interpolation for all data which is pretty useless when you have experiment data

Comment: @TM90 right. Then, `ListDensityPlot` is interpreting your data, correctly, as if you have three rows of z values. Transpose the data to get it into `{{x, y, z}, ...}` form.

Comment: A few points:  1) you have some strings in your data, which you should fix, but that doesn't change that 2) there does seem to be a bug here in the interpolation algorithm, and finally 3) for pure data visualization I don't see why you don't use a `ListLinePlot` like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ihM7f.png)

Comment: @ Jason B, I agree, the reason is that I have just shown 3x651 data, but what I have is 300x651. So ListDensity plot should give more sense to me. I have edited the question again, Do you have some clue ?

Comment: @TM90 I'm sorry, I don't know what to do here.  It's been known for some time that the interpolation used for lists of `{x, y f(x,y)}` is much worse than when it is for an array.  But they don't seem to want to fix this.  I still think for this data the plot with three lines is better, bug if you want the plot with three stripes of uniform width you could do that just graphics primitives fairly easily.  I can look more closely some time this weekend maybe

Comment: @JasonB. I know. I understand your point.  Since I have a huge dataset, looking at strips would be really inefficient. I really appreciate if you could look into this, find some solution.I look forward to hearing from you

Comment: This is a long-standing bug with the triangulation algorithm when the plot area has an extreme aspect ratio. Try rescaling the x values, e.g. `data[[All, 1]] *= 1000;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `MatrixPlot` when I don't want interpolation.

```
mat = Table[
   Select[DeleteCases[data, {_, _, ""}], #[[2]] == i &][[1 ;; 176, 
     3]], {i, {200, 300, 400}}];

MatrixPlot[mat, ImagePadding -> None, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image]

I just took 176 elements on each row to have a square matrix, I reckon you can fix the data yourself someway you see fitting.

**EDIT**

To label the frame, there is another answer already [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/is-it-possible-to-substitute-tick-labels-with-alternative-text)

```
 MatrixPlot[list,  
 FrameTicks -> {
 {{1, 2, 3}, None}, {{{1, 101}, {2, 167}, {3, 188}, {4, 205}}, {{1, "Alice"}, {2,"Bob"}}}
 }]
```

Comment: +1 - this is the closest to what OP is asking for.  If you can add in the `FrameTicks` to match those from `ListDensityPlot` I imagine it's just right

Comment: But the issue with this is that we can not define any labels or automatic ticks for this particular plot.

Comment: @JasonB, Do you use Mathematica for publishing purpose. I would love to know some nice options. I was considering using them for publishing. Do you have any thought on that ?

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to present that data.

```
cf[200] = Blue
cf[300] = Green
cf[400] = Red
Graphics3D[{cf[#[[2]]], Point[#]} & /@ 
  Select[data, VectorQ[#, NumberQ] &], BoxRatios -> {1, 1/4, 1/2}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

The problem with the contour plot is just that its noisy data. You'll need to do some smoothing or functional fitting to get a nice looking contour plot.

(The `Select` is filtering out a few points that are strings in the input data )

Try 2: smoothing each row.  Using `AspectRatio` makes it look a bit less weird too.

```
ListDensityPlot[
 Flatten[Table[
   {#[[1]], y, #[[2]]} & /@ Transpose[MapAt[MeanFilter[#, 5] &,
      Transpose[
       Select[data, 
         VectorQ[#, NumberQ] && #[[2]] == y &][[All, {1, 
          3}]]], {2}]], {y, {200, 300, 400}}], 1],
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image]

Comment: @ george2079 But this is not what I want, I want density 2d plot

Comment: @ george2079, Thanks again this is not I want. As I mentioned before however noisy the curve us, It must plot the actual data. If you look at this data in the second row (y axis from 250 to 350 range) it has many steps along as compared first and third rows. That is pretty wierd

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"  *)

data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/1eMDPXHB"] // ToExpression;
```

Eliminate elements with missing `z` values

```
data2 = DeleteCases[data, {_, _, ""}];
```

For comparison purposes look at data with [`ListPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html)

```
ListPlot3D[data2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
{xMin, xMax} = MinMax[data2[[All, 1]]]

(*  {-0.03, 0.15}  *)
```

Use [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to enable selective trimming of the data

```
Manipulate[
 ListDensityPlot[
  Select[data2, #[[1]] <= xmax &],
  PlotRange -> All],
 {{xmax, xMax}, 0, xMax, xMax/20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Bob Halon, Thanks but again this is not I want, as I mentioned. if the data is interpolated by Mathematica, then there is absolutely no point of making this plot, I am sorry to say so.