# Why are my FrameTicks not working on ArrayPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

For some reason the ticks don't work on this:

```
ArrayPlot[Thread@{Range[0, 1, 0.01]}, AspectRatio -> 4, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotRange -> {{0.`, 1.`}, {0.`, 1.`}},
 FrameTicks -> {{None, {{0, 75}, {1/5, 100}, {2/5, 125}, {3/5, 
      150}, {4/5, 175}, {1, 200}}}, {None, None}},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 BaseStyle -> 
  Directive[Opacity[1], FontFamily -> "Bitstream Charter", 10],
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}]
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4721/5

Comment: You need to remove `PlotRange -> {{0.`, 1.`}, {0.`, 1.`}}`.

Comment: ... interestingly, the way `PlotRange` works inside `ArrayPlot` and `MatrixPlot` is quite different from what we have come to expect based on standard usage patterns inside other `Graphics` objects. So, instead of removing `PlotRange` you can also use `PlotRange->{All,All,{0.,.1}}`. See other interesting examples in the [`ArrayPlot>>Options>>PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPlot.html)

Comment: @kguler Probably a typo (.1 instead of 1), it should be `PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1}}`

Comment: @VLC, right ... meant `{0.,1.}`:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to the fact that your array is actually a vector. If you use `Automatic` in `FrameTicks` you get this:

[image: ArrayPlot]

But you can apply this workaround:

```
ArrayPlot[Thread@{Range[0, 1, 0.01]}, AspectRatio -> 4, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> {{0.`, 1.`}, {0.`, 1.`}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, {{.5, 75}, {.7, 100}, {.9, 125}, {1.1, 150}, {1.3, 175}, 
 {1.5, 200}}}, {None, None}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 BaseStyle -> 
  Directive[Opacity[1], FontFamily -> "Bitstream Charter", 10], 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}]
```

[image: ArrayPlot]

**Update**

To get your gradient you have to remove the `PlotRange` and then specify a new set of ticks.

```
ArrayPlot[Thread@{Range[0, 1, 0.01]}, AspectRatio -> 4, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, {{1, 75}, {20, 100}, {40, 125}, {60, 150}, {80,
       175}, {100, 200}}}, {None, None}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 BaseStyle -> 
  Directive[Opacity[1], FontFamily -> "Bitstream Charter", 10], 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}]
```

[image: ArrayPlot with gradient]

Comment: But where is the gradient!?

Comment: There should be a vertical rainbow gradient

Comment: @TomWellington Your plot didn't produce any either, so I was dealing with `FrameTicks` only.

Comment: @TomWellington See update for the gradient.

Comment: Change `{0,75}` to `{1,75}` to get the first tick.

Comment: Thanks! @VLC that will work. But what if I wanted the plot range to be from 0 to 1, instead of 0 to 100?

Comment: @TomWellington Your range is defined by the length of your array. If you plot `Thread@{Range[0, 1, 0.001]}` the range will be between 0 and 1000.

Comment: @TomWellington Looking at your plot which is thin and has a vertical gradient with ticks on the right, it looks like you are trying to create a colorbar to use with your plots. If that's the case, I would suggest something simple like [in this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11786/5) of mine or something like in [Jens' answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6380/5) if you're looking for more customizations.