# How to set labelled frame ticks on a plot

Tags: plotting, options, labeling, ticks

I wanted to make a plot with custom frame ticks. For example, lets say I want to make a plot

```
 ListPlot[{{1.1,3.9},{2.9,3.1}},
   Axes->None,Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},PlotRange->{{1,3},{3,4}}
 ]
```

but I want to change the frame ticks so that only 1, 2, and 3 show up on the x-axis, and there are only ticks at 3 and 4 on the y-axis and these ticks say "low" and "hi" respectively.

In [the documentation for frameticks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) it gives the example

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0 \[Degree]}, {Pi, 180 \[Degree]}, {2 Pi,  360 \[Degree]}, {3 Pi, 540 \[Degree]}}, {-1/2, 1/2}}
]
```

This is also the pattern suggested in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4721/7182).

Following this pattern, it seems I should try

```
ListPlot[{{1.1,3.9},{2.9,3.1}},
  Axes->None,Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},PlotRange->{{1,3},{3,4}},
  FrameTicks->{{1,2,3},{{3,"low"},{4,"high"}}}
]
```

however, this produces an error. I have also tried

```
Show[
  ListPlot[{{1.1,3.9},{2.9,3.1}},
    Axes->None,Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},PlotRange->{{1,3},{3,4}}
  ],
  FrameTicks->{{1,2,3},{{3,"low"},{4,"high"}}}
]
```

but this also produces an error. Somehow putting `FrameTicks` in quotes in the previous line fixes the error:

```
Show[
  ListPlot[{{1.1,3.9},{2.9,3.1}},
    Axes->None,Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},PlotRange->{{1,3},{3,4}}
  ],
  "FrameTicks"->{{1,2,3},{{3,"low"},{4,"high"}}}
]
```

But I feel like I am doing this wrong way. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, do

```
ListPlot[{{1.1,3.9},{2.9,3.1}},
  Axes->None,Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},PlotRange->{{1,3},{3,4}},
  FrameTicks->{{{{3,"3.0"},{4,"4.0"}},None},{{1,2,3},None}}
]
```

As stated in [the documentation for `FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html), `FrameTicks` expects the option value to be in the form `{{left, right}, {top, bottom}}`, and if it doesn't think you gave an option value in that form, it will look for the form `{x, y}`. Since your `{{3, "low"}, {4, "high"}}` list has length two, it gets confused and thinks you are trying to give it an option value in the form `{{left, right}, {top, bottom}}`. To avoid this, just explicitly put your `FrameTicks` option value in the preferred form.

Note that if you had put three ticks on the y-axis (`FrameTicks -> {{1, 2, 3},
 {{3, "low"}, {3.5, "medium"}, {4, "high"}}}`) it would have worked, since now the y ticks does not have length 2 so Mathematica does not get confused about whether you are using the `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}` form or the `{x, y}` form.