# Why error when exporting pdf of plot?

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format, ticks

I produced a plot using

```
Show[
  ListPlot[{{1.1,3.9},{2.9,3.1}},
    Axes->None,Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},PlotRange->{{1,3},{3,4}}
  ],
  "FrameTicks"->{{1,2,3},{{3,"low"},{4,"high"}}}
]
```

and I wanted to save the plot to a pdf. To save the plot I enter the line

```
Export["plot.pdf",<xxx>];
```

and I copied the plot and pasted where the `<xxx>` is. However, when I go to open the pdf, the y axes are missing. Why is this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can also use `Edit | Copy As | Bitmap`

Answer (score 4):

You use deprecated syntax for `FrameTicks`. Also, `FrameTicks` should be specified as a `Symbol`, not as a `String`. The correct syntax form is `FrameTicks -> {{left,right},{bottom,top}}`:

```
Show[ListPlot[{{1.1, 3.9}, {2.9, 3.1}}, Axes -> None, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, PlotRange -> {{1, 3}, {3, 4}}], 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{3, "low"}, {4, "high"}}, None}, {{1, 2, 3}, None}}]
```

> [image: plot]

With this I have no problem exporting the plot as PDF (*Mathematica* 11.1.1).

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why the y axis is missing in the pdf, but I do know a workaround. One workaround is to simply use a variable to store the plot in and then export the variable:

```
plot=Show[
  ListPlot[{{1.1,3.9},{2.9,3.1}},
    Axes->None,Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},PlotRange->{{1,3},{3,4}}
  ],
  "FrameTicks"->{{1,2,3},{{3,"low"},{4,"high"}}}
];
Export["plot.pdf",plot];
```

An even better solution is to follow the example given in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154879/7182): generate the plot using the command

```
ListPlot[{{1.1,3.9},{2.9,3.1}},
  Axes->None,Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},PlotRange->{{1,3},{3,4}},
  FrameTicks->{{{{3,"3.0"},{4,"4.0"}},None},{{1,2,3},None}}
]
```

(Notice the frame ticks are specified in a different form than you gave in your question.) Then you get the correct pdf both when you copy and paste the plot into the `Export` command or when you store the plot in a variable.