# FrameTicks not working in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I have seen [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13213/why-are-my-frameticks-not-working-on-arrayplot) and [my own post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162575/frameticks-problem-in-datelistplot) from last year. This question seems different. Problem: I can't get the numerical labels of one of the ListPlot axes to display in non-scientific notation.

```
data = {{1, 976506}, {2, 1.91625774*^6}, {3, 2.43912245*^6}, {4, 
    2.32987055*^6}, {5, 2.3669131*^6}, {6, 2.23265532*^6}, {7, 
    2.48768573*^6}, {8, 2.28105368*^6}, {9, 2.82596698*^6}, {10, 
    1.8667454*^6}};
```

I followed the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/labelling-arrayplot-charts) to set up the following:

```
xticks = Transpose[{Range@10, Range@10}]
yticks = Transpose[{Range@7, FindDivisions[{0, 3000000}, 6]}]
Head[yticks[[2, 2]]]
```

The output is:

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 
  9}, {10, 10}}
{{1, 0}, {2, 500000}, {3, 1000000}, {4, 1500000}, {5, 2000000}, {6, 
  2500000}, {7, 3000000}}
Integer
```

The ListPlot command (I took out PlotRange and it did not make any difference):

```
ListPlot[data,
    Joined -> True,
    GridLines -> {Automatic, FindDivisions[{0, 3000000}, 7]},
    FrameTicks -> {yticks, xticks},
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], RGBColor[0, 0.8, 0]},
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12, Bold],
    ImageSize -> 400
 ]
```

[image: plot1]

**My question: How do I get the vertical labels to look like 2 500 000 (or 2,500,000), etc instead of Scientific Notation?**

So then I tried this, which comes from one of the answers to my own post from last year:

```
yticks = Transpose[{Range@7, NumberForm[#, 8, ExponentFunction -> (Null &), DigitBlock -> 3] & /@ FindDivisions[{0, 3000000}, 6]}]
Head[yticks[[2, 2]]]

(this gives a normal-looking output in my notebook, i.e.
{{1, 0}, {2, 500,000}, {3, 1,000,000}, {4, 1,500,000}, {5, 2,000,000}, {6, 
  2,500,000}, {7, 3,000,000}},
but here it looks very messy since NumberForm must be some kind of wrapper)
NumberForm
```

The plot labels looked exactly as above. Finally, I tried this:

```
yticks = Transpose[{Range@7, ToString[#] & /@ {NumberForm[#, 8, ExponentFunction -> (Null &), DigitBlock -> 3] & /@ FindDivisions[{0, 3000000}, 6]}[[1]]}]
Head[yticks[[2, 2]]]

{{1, "0"}, {2, "500,000"}, {3, "1,000,000"}, {4, "1,500,000"}, {5, 
  "2,000,000"}, {6, "2,500,000"}, {7, "3,000,000"}}
String
```

The plot labels looked exactly as above even though they are now Strings!!

Clearly I must be missing something. Any help much appreciated.

System: Mathematica 10 on MacBook Pro 10.14.2 Mojave

Comment: use `Ticks -> {xticks, FindDivisions[{0, 3000000}, 6]}` instead of `FrameTicks->...` or the combination of options `Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}`  and `FrameTicks -> {xticks,   FindDivisions[{0, 3000000}, 6]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues: (1) The option `FrameTicks`  doesn't do anything when `Frame -> False` (you need to use `Ticks` instead of `FrameTicks`), and (2) The way you defined, `yticks` specifies ticks only at the values 1 thru 7.

So, using `Ticks -> {xticks, FindDivisions[{0, 3000000}, 6]}` gives the desired result:

[image]

Comment: It works! The FrameTicks point makes sense in hindsight, duh. I don't quite get your second point but I'll think about it again tomorrow. Thank you very much!

Comment: @pdini,my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.